# How to pass data to the previous view controller if it is the same class Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a table view controller, when I click on a button in the navigationBarItem, I open the same view controller, but with slightly different settings that depend on the flag. By closing this view controller I want to pass the value to the previous one and reload its data with new data, how can I do this? Delegation won't help here, since it's the same class.

```
class LibraryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
...
var isContentFromPlaylist: Bool = false
...
//I open the same VC
@IBAction func addTracksButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LibraryViewController", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Library") as! LibraryViewController
        ...
        navigationController?.showDetailViewController(vc, sender: nil)
    }
...
 @objc private func doneButtonPressed() {
        ...
        //Here I want to change value isContentFromPlaylist to true in previous VC when this VC will close

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Delegation will work because you have two different objects even if they are from the same class.  Normally, one would just change the display rather than showing a copy of the same controller, but it's not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach. Add a property to the class

```
class LibraryViewController {
    //...
    var creator: LibraryViewController?
    //...
}
```

Then, set that property after the controller instantiated...

```
@IBAction func addTracksButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LibraryViewController", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Library") as! LibraryViewController
    //...
    vc.creator = self // Here it is
    //...
    navigationController?.showDetailViewController(vc, sender: nil)
}
```

and use it the way you like:

```
@objc private func doneButtonPressed() {
        ...
        //Here I want to change value isContentFromPlaylist to true in previous VC when this VC will close
        creator?.isContentFromPlaylist = .........
            
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

P.S. To reload data use the UI thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    creator?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Fine! It worked, I was able to transfer data. As I understand,  it's a simplified version of delegation?
But what about the second part of the question? How do I update the tableView in the previous window when I click the doneButton? I can still see the tableView with old data. I try to use creator?.tableView.reloadData (), but it doesn't work.

Comment: @VyacheslavBakinkskiy It shouldn't this way. Updated my answer.

Comment: You can reload your tableView by using Protocols and delegations.

Comment: @Roman Ryzhiy Sorry, but it didn’t work, when I close the second window (VC), I don’t see how the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods work in the first window (VC). It seems to freeze with the same data, and updating the tableView does nothing. In the viewWillAppear method, I would have to get new data from UsersDefaults, which I saved by clicking the Done button in the second window (VC). How do I force the entire first window (VC) to reboot?

Comment: @VyacheslavBakinkskiy `reloadData()` has nothing to do with viewDidLoad etc. Did the `reloadData()` in the creator fire?

Comment: I know it. Yes, reloadData works, but I need to get new values from UserDefaults to fill the tableView.

Comment: Then get them in the `reloadData()`. What is the question?

Comment: All is well, I figured it out. I just needed to force the methods that I had in the viewWillAppear, in which I get the updated data, and then I used the reloadData, as you wrote. Thank!